# where should I place the terminations resistors for RS485?

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, rs485, termination

I want to add termination resistors in RS485 bus .
My systems is Multi-point ( the MCU can send to/receive from 3 external devices) I found out from this [RS-485 CABLE SPECIFICATION GUIDE](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/7/763.html).

that I need termination resistors at both ends of the cable because data is sent bidirectionally.

but I get confused where I should place them.Can someone check if this is correct
[image]

Comment: What you've drawn there (2 termination resistors on one board) is wrong. You need 2 termination resistors for your entire network - so if you have 3 boards, then one of them has no termination resistors, and the other 2 boards have one resistor each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this picture in the guide from [MAXIM](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/7/763.html) is self-explanatory: -

[image]

- one resistor at one end of the common shared multipoint cable and one resistor at the other end.
- don't use star-cabling techniques - the multi-drop cable has to be used and physically, it can snake this way or that way but keep tee-off point lengths to a minimum.

It's all about preventing data corruptions due to fast data signals reflecting from the open end termination of the cable.

Comment: thank you for commenting but there is no twisted cable I will place on my board 9 pos connector (3*RS485 ports) after Max485 IC as shown in my question and I don't know if I made the right connection .can you check it please. sheet RS485 Contain Max485

Comment: You need to show what the screw terminal connector connects to then. You also need to keep the wires/connections to those external devices quite short too. If you think that you can tee-off to three separate RS485 cables of any distance, you can't. You can tee-off to one external cable which can connect to multiple devices but they will need to be daisy chained like in the picture above. Twisting is unimportant for the theory but very useful in practice.

Comment: many thanks I changed it

Comment: Changed what? I don't understand????

Comment: I was confused.the slaves should be connected on the twisted cable not on the board (I made 3 RS485 PORTS). SO I deleted the connectors and I kept one with 3 pos(Gnd,A,B) which will be connected to the twisted cable

Comment: That's the way to go and, at the far end of that cable place the 2nd terminating resistor.

Comment: @walid24 you can't make a star network with central point and three ends. Or you can but that is not recommended, unless the stubs are very short. You should have one linear bus with two ends, the termination resistors should be at both ends, and the devices can be anywhere on the bus between resistors.

Comment: @Justme thank you for your comment . It is daisy chained connection.

Comment: @Andyaka I got you